# Fetch self referencing child and sub child based on parent Id

Tags: sql

I am not able to fetch the subchild from the parentId postgres sql.

I have the following table below, which is a self referencing table.

```
INSERT INTO public.dc_device_profile(
device_profile_id, device_profile_number, device_type, image_index, scale_type, state_index, parent_device_profile_id)
VALUES (nextval('device_profile_id_sequence'), 'ASIndis','Fresh444', '4444test', 'Fresh444', 'test222',3);
```

Let the table have the following data:

```
1   "AS2"       "FreshPro"  "test"      "FreshPro"  "test"      null
2   "AS4"       "Fresh2222" "test"      "Fresh222"  "test"      1
3   "AS55"      "Fresh122"  "122test"   "Fresh1"    "test11"    1
5   "ASIndis"   "Fresh444"  "4444test"  "Fresh444"  "test222"   3
```

Query:

```
SELECT T1.device_profile_id, T1.device_id, T1.device_profile_number, T1.device_type, 
T1.image_index, T1.scale_type, T1.state_index, T1.tenant_id, T1.parent_device_profile_id
FROM dc_device_profile AS T1 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT parent_device_profile_id FROM dc_device_profile WHERE 
 dc_device_profile.parent_device_profile_id = 1) AS T2 
 ON T2.parent_device_profile_id = T1.device_profile_id OR T1.parent_device_profile_id = 1
 GROUP BY T1.parent_device_profile_id, T1.device_profile_id
```

The below query returns only direct childs and not the child of child.

Output:

```
1   23  "AS2"   "FreshPro"  "test"      "FreshPro"  "test"      2   null
2   23  "AS4"   "Fresh2222" "test"      "Fresh222"  "test"      2   1
3   44  "AS55"  "Fresh122"  "122test"   "Fresh1"    "test11"    2   1
```

Expected output:(missing value last row with device_profile_id with 5)

```
1   "AS2"       "FreshPro"  "test"      "FreshPro"  "test"      null
2   "AS4"       "Fresh2222" "test"      "Fresh222"  "test"      1
3   "AS55"      "Fresh122"  "122test"   "Fresh1"    "test11"    1
5   "ASIndis"   "Fresh444"  "4444test"  "Fresh444"  "test222"   3
```

Comment: The desired output is the same as sample data. You can `select * from ..`

Comment: Your subquery condition is backwards - from your description T2 should return the device_profile_id and join that to T1.parent_device_profile_id